# Redmine installation

Tags: linux, apache, redmine

i have been fighting for many years to install Redmine on Debian/Wheezy.

I  followed the following tutorial: [enter link description here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall).

But when I restart my Apache server, the redmine web page only displays the list of the files of the Remdine directory.

[image: My Reminde web site]

Could you please help to solve this problem?
Thank you

EDIT:
I am making progress... Phusion Passenger was not installed, so I did it.
But, I still have another error which is displayed when I connect to my Redmine web page:

```
Permission denied - /etc/redmine/default/database.yml (Errno::EACCES)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `read'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
```

The permissions are the following ones:
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 112 août   8 18:11 database.yml
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 911 août   8 18:11 session.yml

Comment: You linked to the instructions but didn't explain which steps you did or where you got stuck

Comment: Also, in your question `i have been fighting for many years to install Redmine on Debian/Wheezy` . For many years? srsly??

Comment: @Brandin<br/>
First sorry for the mistake, I used "years" instead of "hours" <br/>

I followed the following steps:<br/>
-I installed mysql et apache2<br/>
-I installed redmine, redmine-mysql, ruby-dev and libapache2-mod-passenger from the wheezy backports<br/>
-I followed the step 2 to 8 of the tutorial that I mentionned in my first question<br/>
Finally, I go to  http://myserver/redmine and the only thing that I can see is the list of the files of the redmine directory.
It looks like the code of the web application does not run.<br/>
Is there any log files that I should inspect? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally successed to install and run Redmine.

The permission on the database.yml file was correct but not on the parent directory.

Now it works.

Comment: I am getting same issue, following this https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-redmine-on-ubuntu-20-04/. Trying for 3-4 days